# Hibernate - Retrieve entity locked with pesimistic write lock

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, locking

I made some research about locking DB entities with Hibernate and saw that it is possible to lock entities explicitly with the `Session.lock()` method.

However, I think I need some clarification here, as I could not find any answers in the Documentation:

Can I retrieve entities that are currently locked, for example, with `LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` (in another session) and then acquire the lock explcitly afterwards with the `Session.lock()` method or do I have to specify the lock mode right when I retrieve the entity?
If the latter is true, why is there even the possibility to explicitly set the lock mode for an entity? Is it just to upgrade the lock mode, e.g., from pessimistic read to pessimistic write?

Comment: The lock mode is not on the entities but on the database row/table.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli So what happens if I retrieve the same entity once with PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock and once without a lock? Will the retrieve without lock fail with an exception, since I shouldn’t be able to read the entity?

Comment: PESSIMISTIC_WRITE will execute a select .. for update and lock the row. So you cannot retrieve it in another transaction